# Whatsapp very slow, ads show up randomly every 10 minutes

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, ads

Since 2 days ago my whatsapp is very slow.
Every message needs 30 minutes.Maybe 1 hour.

Internet is fine. I can surf the web and stuff. However, look at this screenshot. Nothing gets sent. If I restart Whatsapp, things works again.
Let me show you a screenshot.

[image: IMG:]

Also there are ads that often show up randomly. Here is another annoying ads

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

The screenshot I took have a file name called `Screenshot_2019-02-07-15-30-44-985_com.game.flowoneline.png`.
The thing is those annoying ads still show up even when flowonline game is gone.

Comment: Please mention your device name and android version. Have you enabled data usage for whatsapp application?

Comment: I don't understand what the  title: are the ads showing inside WhatsApp?

Comment: Unless things have changed, Whatsapp does not show ads. Backup those games, then remove them (not playing for 1-2 days won't hurt). Check if there are not returning. If you dont want to remove them, install a firewall & block them. Allow Whatsapp & other important apps to go through the firewall.

Comment: From the screenshots that you posted, it looks like you are using MIUI. Is it true? I have a solution that will work for MIUI (thanks to its great permission controls) and you don't have to uninstall the game.

Comment: However, I would always advise you against using using such apps/games which show such intrusive advertising. In your scenario, it is definitely not WhatsApp that is showing advertisements (It has never done that **yet**). Moreover, I would always suggest you to download apps from the play store because Google usually gets rid of such apps, very often, which reduce the quality of user experience.

Comment: how do you do it? Settings and change permission control for flowline?